# Manhwa in which the female lead was afraid of the male lead, since she remembered that he killed her in the previous timeline

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

There’s this manhwa I read a long time ago.

I only remember the situation where the female lead was sent by her father to a summer house or something like that to recover herself. She remembered how the male lead (ML) killed her in her past life and wrote this down somewhere. By chance, the ML found what she wrote and read it, but couldn’t imagine that he would kill her, because he loves her. So he visits her in her summer house.

Does anyone know this manhwa? (Sorry for my bad English.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead or the male lead?